# I am getting an ERROR when compiling Angular 6 project

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, angular6

when starting my project `ng serve` i get this error.
updated my ts and did not help.

here is the error

```
    ERROR in node_modules/@types/node/assert.d.ts(3,68): error TS1144: '{' or ';' expected.
    node_modules/@types/node/assert.d.ts(57,68): error TS1144: '{' or ';' expected.
    node_modules/@types/node/assert.d.ts(66,94): error TS1144: '{' or ';' expected.
    node_modules/@types/node/assert.d.ts(66,101): error TS1005: ';' expected.
    node_modules/@types/node/assert.d.ts(66,104): error TS1005: ';' expected.
    node_modules/@types/node/assert.d.ts(68,98): error TS1144: '{' or ';' expected.
    node_modules/@types/node/assert.d.ts(68,105): error TS1005: ';' expected.
    node_modules/@types/node/assert.d.ts(68,108): error TS1005: ';' expected.
    node_modules/@types/node/assert.d.ts(76,47): error TS1144: '{' or ';' expected.
    node_modules/@types/node/assert.d.ts(76,53): error TS1005: ';' expected.
    node_modules/@types/node/assert.d.ts(76,56): error TS1005: ';' expected.
    node_modules/@types/node/assert.d.ts(106,61): error TS1005: ';' expected.
    node_modules/@types/node/base.d.ts(10,1): error TS1084: Invalid 'reference' directive syntax.
    node_modules/@types/node/base.d.ts(11,1): error TS1084: Invalid 'reference' directive syntax.
    node_modules/@types/node/base.d.ts(12,1): error TS1084: Invalid 'reference' directive syntax.
    node_modules/@types/node/base.d.ts(13,1): error TS1084: Invalid 'reference' directive syntax.
    node_modules/@types/node/ts3.4/base.d.ts(10,1): error TS1084: Invalid 'reference' directive syntax.
    node_modules/@types/node/ts3.4/base.d.ts(11,1): error TS1084: Invalid 'reference' directive syntax.
    node_modules/@types/node/ts3.4/base.d.ts(12,1): error TS1084: Invalid 'reference' directive syntax.
    node_modules/@types/node/ts3.4/base.d.ts(13,1): error TS1084: Invalid 'reference' directive syntax.
    node_modules/@types/node/ts3.6/base.d.ts(10,1): error TS1084: Invalid 'reference' directive syntax.
    node_modules/@types/node/ts3.6/base.d.ts(11,1): error TS1084: Invalid 'reference' directive syntax.
    node_modules/@types/node/ts3.6/base.d.ts(12,1): error TS1084: Invalid 'reference' directive syntax.
    node_modules/@types/node/ts3.6/base.d.ts(13,1): error TS1084: Invalid 'reference' directive syntax.`
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This is probably an incompatibility issue between your TypeScript version and some of your *@types* packages. I'll walk you through the solution with a step by step example:

1. Go to your *package.json* and look for you TypeScript and *@types* versions:

```json
  "devDependencies": {
    // ...
    "@types/deep-freeze": "0.1.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "3.5.10",
    "@types/lodash.isequal": "4.5.5",
    "@types/lodash.mergewith": "4.6.6",
    "@types/lodash.remove": "4.7.6",
    "@types/lodash.some": "4.6.6",
    // ...
    "typescript": "2.9.2",
    // ...
  }
```

2. For each of your *@types* packages [do](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/47250#issuecomment-687701880): `npm dist-tags @types/<your-types-package-name>`. You'll now see a table that indicates which TypeScript version works with each of the *@types* package version
3. Update your *@types* in your *package.json* with the corresponding versions

**If the solution does not work try updating TypeScript to a newer version!**

Answer (score 5):

In case your using **"typescript": "~3.1.6"** in the package.json file, change   **"@types/node"** version to    **"@types/node": "14.6.2",** in the package.json file, That solved my problem..

Comment: Very nice! This was my problem too, It happens when typescript is not compatible with your node version.